# How to use the DWB local planner

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, navfn, nav-core, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I was wondering if you can help me to find out how to use the [DWB_local_planner](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/dwb_local_planner) in [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base).

I have already installed all the packages in the [This](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation).

You can find the part of the launcher where I call the *move_base*.

```
<!--- Run move_base -->
<node respawn="false" pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find dsi_airbus_manager)/conf/move_base/common_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find dsi_airbus_manager)/conf/move_base/common_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find dsi_airbus_manager)/conf/move_base/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find dsi_airbus_manager)/conf/move_base/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find dsi_airbus_manager)/conf/move_base/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" />
    <param name="controller_frequency" value="10.0" />
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="global_planner/GlobalPlanner"/>
    <param name="recovery_behavior_enabled" value="false"/>>
    <param name="planner_patience" value="5.0"/>
    <param name="controller_patience" value="15.0"/>
    <param name="shutdown_costmaps" value="false"/>
    <param name="oscillation_timeout" value="30.0"/>
    <param name="oscillation_distance" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="planner_frequency" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="max_planning_retries" value="15"/>
</node>
```

At the moment I use the *TEB_local_planner*. But I have no idea how I can call the *DWB_local_planner* in the launch file.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312524/how-to-use-the-dwb-local-planner/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2019-01-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To use DWB in `move_base`, you need to use the [nav_core_adapter](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/nav_core_adapter) (documentation behind that link)

In your case, I would replace the line  `<param name="base_local_planner" value="teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" />`
with the following

```
<param name="base_local_planner" value="nav_core_adapter::LocalPlannerAdapter" />
<param name="LocalPlannerAdapter/planner_name" value="dwb_local_planner::DWBLocalPlanner" />
```

Then you would need to edit the parameters in `local_costmap_params.yaml` at the very least to have them loaded in the DWBLocalPlanner namespace.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-01-11**:
Thanks a lot David..

Is it possible to provide a WIKI page for the DWB_local_planner](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/dwb_local_planner) in order to avoid these questions?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-01-23**:
Documentation to this effect does exist (below).

https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/nav_core_adapter#parameter-setup

**Comment by [Sgm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50740/sgm/) on 2020-01-07**:
Hi, could you please extend how to modify local_costmap_params.yaml. Is not clear for me which namespace should be used to load the costmap in DWBLocalPlanner, since the costmap_adapter should also be used. Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2020-01-10**:
@sgm please open your own question.

**Comment by [Sgm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50740/sgm/) on 2020-01-23**:
Sorry, I thought it was highly related. Here you go :) https://answers.ros.org/question/341513/how-to-configure-local_costmapyaml-to-use-costmapadapter-in-dwb-planner/